# Sharepoint 2010 Document Library Event Receivers - - - How to capture event when the document is being openned

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sharepoint-2010

There is event handler when item is being added, deleted, checked in or checked out . . . but no handler when the item is being open is there any way I could capture the event when the item is being opened? Please help.

Thanks a lot

Comment: Thanks Joel for editing the tag
I am just wondering if anybody gets a chance to look this. 

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

I think you may have to resort to a HttpHandler or HttpModule.  We are running into the same issue and will let you know if we find anything out.

Comment: Thanks Kirk, I really appreciate that since it is still remained unsolved. 

aYus